# Multidimensional integral limits question

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve an integral of the form

$$\int_{R^3}dxdydz f(x, y, z)$$ where I already know that I need to use the following change of variables

$$\begin{cases}
u = x+y\\
v = y+z-x\\
w = y-z
\end{cases}$$

these equations identify 3 lines in the 3D space. From the Jacobian determinant we also get that $dxdydz = \frac{1}{4}dudvdw$.

Now I have a problem with the integration limits. I see that we have to find a way to set these limits in such a way that we visit every point of the space since we were integrating over $R^3$, so I am pretty sure that we can set the first integral like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ in any of the variables, but **how do we set the limits for the other ones?**

Comment: As $x$ and $y$ each range over $(-\infty, \infty)$, over what interval does $u$ range?  (This comment implicitly uses that the transformation of variables is linear/invertible.)

Comment: $u\in (-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: Now, do the similar thing two more times.

Comment: ok this was easy, but what about $w$ for example? I have an undetermined form $\infty-\infty$

Comment: Do you?  We're not *evaluating* anything at infinity; we can't, because $\pm \infty$ are not numbers.

Comment: Sorry I am not following

Comment: $x$, $y$, and $z$ range over intervals of actual numbers.  None of these are ever $\infty$ or $-\infty$.  As $x$, $y$, and $z$ range over those intervals, is there a minimum value that $w$ takes?  Does it take values less than any minimum we could specify?  What label do we attach to the idea of an expression that takes values less than any number that can be specified?

Comment: So you are saying they all range in $(-\infty, \infty)$, ok it actually makes sense now that I think about it.

Comment: (Also, if you intend to *minimize* something, you add the least amounts you can and subtract the largest amounts you can, so in $y+z-x$ you should be thinking of $(small)+(small) - (large)$ which unambiguously takes you to $-\infty$.)